# Search for sub-directory and delete content if older than specified time

Tags: python, search, optimization

I am really new to python and coding in general and am looking for some help with optimizing my code. I am attempting to write a script that will locate all "Temp" folders under a certain path, find the newest file age for each, and proceed on with the deletion only if no files found are newer than 1 hour old. Currently the deletion mechanism is not implemented but that should be easy enough to add once the files have been located and checked.

My current iteration has no problem running on my test folder structure of a few thousand files but when I try and run it on the real thing (5b+ files) it of course takes forever. Almost all of these files reside outside of the "Temp" folders. Is there a way to isolate the searching of files to only Temp folders?

Below is my current code.

```
import os
import fnmatch
import time
import calendar


def find_newest_file(path):
    for cur_path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            yield os.path.join(cur_path, filename)

matches = []
latest_file = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("--Path To Network Share--"):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(dirnames, '*Temp'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            latest_file.append(max(find_newest_file(os.path.join(root, filename)),
                              key=os.path.getmtime))

counter = 0
newestfileage = []
for name in matches:
    newestfileage.append((calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) - os.stat(latest_file[counter]).st_mtime) / 3600)
    counter += 1

if min(newestfileage) < 1:
    print("\nToo new of an Entry in Temp folders, stopping.\nNewest file is only", min(newestfileage)*60,"Minutes Old")
else:
    print("\nAll Temp files are older than 1 hour old, proceeding.")
```

If there is an entirely different approach to this I am all ears.

Comment: Do you really have to do this using Python? I would suggest to use the unix shell executable named `find` with its -mtime option like here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194863/delete-files-older-than-x-days

Comment: Only start iterating over the files if `os.path.basename(root) == 'Temp'`?

Comment: Also, you are `walk`ing over directories more than once, no, when you call `find_newest_file`.... this should only use `os.walk` *once* to accomplish what you are trying to do... What are you trying to get into `matches`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you only need to do the following:

```
import re
import os

temp_regex = re.compile(r'.*Temp')
matches = []
latest_file = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("--Path To Network Share--"):
    if temp_regex.match(os.path.basename(root)):
        matches.append(root)
        fullnames = (os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in filenames)
        latest_file.append(max(fullnames, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

And dispense with your `find_newest_file` function, which initiates *more `os.walks`* over matching directories, but you visit them as many times as they are below a root that you give to `find_newest_file`. This makes you scale horrifically.

As an aside, don't keep a `counter` variable if you are incrementing in every iteration, use `enumerate` instead:

```
newestfileage = []
for i, name in enumerate(matches):
    newestfileage.append((calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) - os.stat(latest_file[i]).st_mtime) / 3600)
```

Or better yet, I think you just need to iterate over `for file in latest_file` since you never use `match` and only use `i` to index into `latest_file`. Indeed, the above could probably be accomplished during your `os.walk` pass:

```
temp_regex = re.compile(r'.*Temp')
matches = []
latest_file = []
newestfileage = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("--Path To Network Share--"):
    if temp_regex.match(os.path.basename(root)):
        matches.append(root)
        fullnames = (os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in filenames)
        latest = max(fullnames, key=os.path.getmtime)
        latest_file.append(latest)
        newestfileage.append(calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) - os.stat(latest).st_mtime) / 3600)
```